# Can we have reuse MS Teams Praise dialog in Personal App?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I want to reuse the MS Teams OOTB Praise functionality in my Personal MS Teams app, is there a way to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not supported. You may suggest this feature at the [Microsoft Teams feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Comment: IS there a way we can achieve the same functionality with apis or something?

Comment: Although there is no direct API for this but there are few app templates for a similar purpose - 

https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-workplaceawards
https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-coworker-appreciation